# Can you import a css file and use sass to iterate each of the rules and append !important?

Tags: css, sass, stylesheet, meta

Can you take a file and update each css rule slightly with sass? E.g.

style.scss

```
  .bold {
    font-weight: 600
  }
  .bolder {
    font-weight: 800
  }
// ...
```

style-important.scss

```
// Here I want to import and produce the following:

  .bold-important {
    font-weight: 600 !important;
  }
  .bolder-important {
    font-weight: 800 !important;
  }
```

Can sass produce this? Can another css preprocessor accomplish this?

Comment: If you have to put `!important` after all of your rules, you should reconsider the design of your CSS.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Or reconsider working, I'm sure designing good css is the top priority at your company.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but Sass will not be able to do that. The best that you can do is an loop in an array like this:

```
@each $animal in puma, sea-slug, egret, salamander {
    .#{$animal}-icon {
      background-image: url('/images/#{$animal}.png');
    }
}
```

But it will not resolve your problem

Comment: How hard would it be to add to sass? This would be an incredibly useful feature.

Comment: I don't know how hard it would be to implement it but yes it would be an interesting feature. After that it should be known that sass is more oriented towards the fast generation of the css and not the parsing of it.

Comment: thanks for trying, though it does not answer the original question so I can't give you anything.